# obfsproxy fails to build because it can't find event2/util.h

Tags: make

I'm trying to build [obfsproxy](https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy.html.en). These steps all work fine:

```
# git clone https://git.torproject.org/obfsproxy.git
# cd obfsproxy
# ./autogen.sh
# ./configure
```

But then I get to:

```
# make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/obfsproxy'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I. -I./src  -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Werror -l/usr/local/libevent/include/ -l/usr/local/libevent/include/ -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-all -fwrapv -fPIE --param ssp-buffer-size=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-strict-overflow -MT container.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/container.Tpo -c -o container.o `test -f 'src/container.c' || echo './'`src/container.c
In file included from src/container.c:14:
src/util.h:22:47: error: event2/util.h: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [container.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/obfsproxy'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the package list any dependencies that you might not have installed (probably packages called `-devel`, `-dev` or similar for each dependency)? But the `event2/util.h` file name looks like a file that should either be in the repository you cloned, or else generated during the build. It might be a hickup/upstream bug, try `git pull` and do the `./autogen.sh` etc dance from the beginning.

Comment: hi.vonbrand: firstly i installed libevent as follows:

Comment: No details on how you installed... and looking again at your compile line, it looks like the problem lies there. Where is libevent installed? From source, into `/usr/local`, or as a package into `/usr`?